# How to remove list of objects from another list of Objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have two lists `json`, one called **subscribers** and the other called **following**.

**following**:

```
{ 
  0: { id: "u0", username: "user0", avatar: "user0.png" },
  1: { id: "u1", username: "user1", avatar: "user1.png" },
  2: { id: "u2", username: "user2", avatar: "user2.png" },
  3: { id: "u3", username: "user3", avatar: "user3.png" },
  4: { id: "u4", username: "user4", avatar: "user4.png" },
  5: { id: "u5", username: "user5", avatar: "user5.png" }
}
```

**subscribers**:

```
{ 
  1: { id: "u1", username: "user1", avatar: "user1.png" },
  4: { id: "u4", username: "user4", avatar: "user4.png" }
}
```

I want to remove the *subscribers* from the *following*, `[ following - subscribers = remaining list of following ]`.

How can I delete them depend on the `id` property in each object in both list?

Comment: Do the keys of the objects always align with the id? i.e. is `n: { id: "un" ...}` always true?

Comment: No, they are different .. by I list them here just to explain the structure for the objects. @nbwoodward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lodash is quite helpful:
_.pullBy(following, subscribers, 'id')

Comment: I used this `_.pullAllBy(array, values, [iteratee=_.identity])` and it was really helpful .. thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your keys line up with your ids:

```
f = {
  0: { id: "u0", username: "user0", avatar: "user0.png" },
  1: { id: "u1", username: "user1", avatar: "user1.png" },
  2: { id: "u2", username: "user2", avatar: "user2.png" },
  3: { id: "u3", username: "user3", avatar: "user3.png" },
  4: { id: "u4", username: "user4", avatar: "user4.png" },
  5: { id: "u5", username: "user5", avatar: "user5.png" }
}

s = {
  1: { id: "u1", username: "user1", avatar: "user1.png" },
  4: { id: "u4", username: "user4", avatar: "user4.png" }
}

for( i in s ){
  delete f[i]
}
```

Comment: No, the keys are `0,1,2,....` but the `id` are different not line up with the keys. I want to check the id in both objects and if they match .. delete the matched object form `following` object.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on follower's keys (or values) to create a new object based on entries that do not appear in subscribers:

```js
let followers = {
  0: { id: "u0", username: "user0", avatar: "user0.png" },
  1: { id: "u1", username: "user1", avatar: "user1.png" },
  2: { id: "u2", username: "user2", avatar: "user2.png" },
  3: { id: "u3", username: "user3", avatar: "user3.png" },
  4: { id: "u4", username: "user4", avatar: "user4.png" },
  5: { id: "u5", username: "user5", avatar: "user5.png" }
}

let subscribers = {
  1: { id: "u1", username: "user1", avatar: "user1.png" },
  4: { id: "u4", username: "user4", avatar: "user4.png" }
}

followers = Object.keys(followers).reduce((acc, current) => !Object.values(subscribers).some(sub => sub.id === followers[current].id) ? {...acc, [current]: followers[current]} : acc, {})
console.log(followers)
```

Or you can iterate followers' keys and delete "duplicates" instead:

```js
let followers = {
  0: { id: "u0", username: "user0", avatar: "user0.png" },
  1: { id: "u1", username: "user1", avatar: "user1.png" },
  2: { id: "u2", username: "user2", avatar: "user2.png" },
  3: { id: "u3", username: "user3", avatar: "user3.png" },
  4: { id: "u4", username: "user4", avatar: "user4.png" },
  5: { id: "u5", username: "user5", avatar: "user5.png" }
};

let subscribers = {
  1: { id: "u1", username: "user1", avatar: "user1.png" },
  4: { id: "u4", username: "user4", avatar: "user4.png" }
};

Object.keys(followers).forEach(current => {
  if (Object.values(subscribers).some(sub => sub.id === followers[current].id)) {
    delete followers[current];
  }
});
console.log(followers);
```